# Correct Use of Mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoskin

I usually work with [`mongoskin`](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) because I like to be close to the database. Usually, I do a setup with a file like `db.coffee`, that contains just this:

```
mongo = require 'mongoskin'
# either local
module.exports = mongo.db 'mongodb://localhost/database'
# or remote
module.exports = mongo.db 'mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<db>?auto_reconnect=true'
```

Then I use it in my other sources:

```
db = require 'db'
users = db.collection 'users'
# Now use the collection in handlers and middleware
```

This seems to work perfectly fine when I am using a local mongo server, I've had an uptime for months and it never turned out to be a problem.

However, when I am using the remote second, I get problem if the server runs longer than just a few minutes - the connection to the mongodb seems lost, despite `auto_reconnect`. I guess this is because the `localhost` connection is never closed automatically.

However this led me to thinking if I am maybe using `mongoskin` in a wrong way, or if there's simply a bug with the `auto_reconnect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ensure mongoskin is using the 1.0.0 or higher driver

Comment: When I do that, I get an error about something like `_serverstatus`.